# Restore Seed with Password

Tags: electrum

I am running Electrum 2.3.2. I had 2-factor authentication enabled with Google Authenticator, but then got a new phone. I know the password to the wallet but do not have the 2-factor code anymore. I do not know my seed. Is there a way for me to get access to my coins in this situation?

When looking at the wallet file I do not see a key entry in the text.

Unfortunately I am only seeing how people do this when they have the seed but not the password, which is the opposite of my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2FA wallet means there are two distinct sets of private keys, one you hold in your wallet, and one held by a third party. Normally you are authorizing the third party to sign transactions with their private keys on your behalf by giving them a valid 2FA code. In the case of Electrum, the third party is a company named TrustedCoin.

[image]

Their terms of service explicitly state that there is no recovery service for lost 2FA tokens.

**3. Integration with 3rd-Party Wallets**

*If you forget your one-time password generator, we offer no way to recreate it.  You will need to use your second key to move your funds to a new address.*

From the information presented you will need to find your Electrum seed to restore both halves of your wallet, or find a backup of your phone that contains the 2FA token files. iOS for example will  back these up into iTunes, it is likely that Android devices have similar backups that will contain them as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the password then you can login. To get the seed,there is 
Files Wallet Tools Help.
Click on Wallet.
In the drop down menu select Seed.
Enter your password.
It should show your Seed